# What does it mean for the partial derivatives of $f(x, y$) to be $0$ in the outline of the method of exact equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In the outline of the method of exact equations given in the textbook below the authors write  $\partial f/\partial y \equiv 0$ and $\partial f/\partial x \equiv 0$ and denotes these as $M(x, y)$ and $N(x, y)$ and I'm very much confused by this. Does this mean $M(x, y)$ and $N(x, y)$ have to equate to $0$? Doesn't make sense with the examples given later in the text. I'm guessing the answer is a basic fact that I'm overlooking.

[Outline of the method (Differential Equations by Simmons and Krantz)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLnMb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you're solving an exact differential equation, you're looking for a solution in the form $f(x,y)=c$. Since this is the solution of the differential equation, it's derivative with respect to $x$ will be our original equation. Hence, when you implicitly take the derivative of $f(x,y)=c$ you get the total derivative
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=0.
$$
For exact differential equations, we represent the two partial derivatives as $M$ and $N$ respectively. The reason your textbook says that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are identically zero is because if we were to implicitly take the partial derivative of $f(x,y)=c$ with respect to $x,$ we can easily see the result would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0.$ However, the partial derivative here (given by $M(x,y)$ in the differential equation) is still a function, for which all legitimate values of $x$ and $y$, the result is zero.

Comment: No, you're missing the main point. When they ask about how the equation can hold *everywhere*, they're not asking about restricting to level curves of $f$. They're saying that $f$ would have to be a constant. The point of solving these differential equations is that we're looking for *curves* along which the expression (differential form) becomes $0$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense, but I don't see how my answer contradicts anything you've said. If the partial derivatives are all zero then $f$ must be constant, and everything above holds true, does it not?

Comment: When you differentiate implicitly you do not get $\partial f\partial x$ *identically zero* (not “equivalent to”).

Comment: Okay. I think I see what you mean and I've patched up some of the phrasing to try and fix my answer.